# Convert the an Excel generated file to PDF in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, exceljs, filesaver.js

I want to convert the excel file into pdf. Likewise, I had previously generated the excel file with `excelJs` and save it on pc with `file-saver` plugin.

Now I just want to convert that same excel file blob into the Pdf file and then save to the pdf.

Here is my code snippet for saving the excel file.

```
const buf = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
const data = new Blob([buf], { type: fileType })
FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'User Listing Report' + fileExtension);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to use a combination of the following JavaScript libraries there's this project https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv
but i think in the server there is some problems with this method
i hope i help u !!!